# How to break out of 12 col grid with bootstrap 4 flexbox grid?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

*When I heard bootstrap 4 was going to employ flexbox for a grid system I was really excited. I thought that this would deploy the fast and useful element sizing that flexbox is known for. However it seems that it just adds some (major) functionality to the current 12 col grid system.*

**Does Bootstrap 4 make it any easier to relate column widths in a non 12 col layout?**

Like how flex boxes can be related to each other simply by specifying the horizontal space to divide using flex-item properties like `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`.

[1:5][-----3:5-----][1:5]

This would be done with a simple `flex:3;` on the col2 item. But still seems impossible in bootstrap 4? Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Maybe using Sass Mixins to modify the grid classes would be the best solution like on this [advanced grid tricks page](http://willschenk.com/bootstrap-advanced-grid-tricks/), but it would seem like this would be something natural to pull from flexbox! =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 has flexbox, and it's still based on a 12-unit grid, however there is also a new [**auto-layout grid**](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns) which allows for *any* number of columns...

**Auto-layout columns:**
http://codeply.com/go/JbGGN4Ok3A

---

Also, using **SASS**, you can change the number of grid columns using the `$grid-columns` variable. In your example, a 10-unit grid would work. Combine this with auto-layout and you can get:

[1:5][-----3:5-----][1:5]

**SASS**

```
  $enable-flex:true;
  $grid-columns: 10;
  $grid-gutter-width: 15px;
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs">
              1:5
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-6">
               3:5
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs">
               1:5
         </div>
 </div>
```

http://codeply.com/view/WG1jllYC2K

Note: You can also use the `$grid-gutter-width` variable to change the spacing between columns.

***UPDATE***

**Bootstrap 4.0.0**: https://www.codeply.com/go/6jTDGBnPIO

---

As of **Bootstrap 4** (alpha 6) the auto-layout `.col` is now used for flex-grow so that you can create **half-unit** column layouts. The `2.5--7--2.5` layout is mathematically very close to your `1.5--3.5--1.5` (10-unit) so this may be another option instead of the custom SASS 10 unit grid.
http://www.codeply.com/go/kBqRVNPE6E