# How to divide a div into 13 equal parts using bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to divide a div into 13 equal parts using bootstrap, how to do it?

Comment: the bootstrap grid is split into 12 parts, not 13

Comment: Define your own classes as Bootstrap doesn't have any for 13 in a row

Comment: Try using auto-layout columns: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I know that a bootstrap grid is divided into 12 parts, it was asked in one of the interviews and I couldn't get an answer to the question,  hence asked.

Comment: see this dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799090/how-to-break-out-of-12-col-grid-with-bootstrap-4-flexbox-grid/38828165#38828165

Answer (score 1):

Not with bootstrap, but very simple with flex

```css
.foo {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
   <div class="item">z</div>
   <div class="item">z</div>
   <div class="item">z</div>
   <div class="item">z</div>
   <div class="item">z</div>
   <div class="item">z</div>
   <div class="item">z</div>
   <div class="item">z</div>
   <div class="item">z</div>
   <div class="item">z</div>
   <div class="item">z</div>
   <div class="item">z</div>
   <div class="item">z</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- bootstrap already provides the div with maximum of 12 in a container
  **you have to use css instead**

thanks